# Creating an array of pictureboxes in windows form (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to create an array/list of picturebox objects that are declared and added to the form on button click (Meaning that I'm not creating multiple objects with my array, but plan to if I can get this to run). Not getting errors, but the pictureboxes themselves do not appear on the form.

```
private void spawn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureTest[0] = new PictureBox();

    pictureTest[0].Image = Properties.Resources.testimage;
    pictureTest[0].Location = new Point(500, 250);
    pictureTest[0].Name = "spawn1";
    pictureTest[0].Size = new Size(50, 50);
    pictureTest[0].TabIndex = 98;
    pictureTest[0].TabStop = false;

    this.Controls.Add(pictureTest[0]);

}
```

Through the course of my research, I've mainly just gotten the advice to use `this.Controls.Add`, but that doesn't seem to be my issue here. My array is declared earlier with:

```
PictureBox[] pictureTest = new pictureTest[100];
```

Comment: What does Visual Basic have to do with this? You know VB and C# are not the same thing, right?

Comment: Ugh, meant visual studio, probably should have put windows form. Kind of a mess right now, I'll see if I can figure out how to edit

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the first line of `spawn_Click` and then Run with Debugging, does the breakpoint get hit? And check the Window size, maybe the window size < the position where you put the PictureBox so it 'appears' out of view.

Comment: It does, and I remember trying this earlier and seeing that the properties were getting set correctly with a watch window.

Comment: The form size is 630, 550 and I'm setting the picture box to 500, 250

Comment: Hard-coding [0] does not make sense when you want multiple boxes.  Use a List or add a variable that keeps track of the count.  Giving them all the same Location is why it looks like there is only one, they are on top of each other.

Comment: I'm only attempting to create one to test whether I can get an array to work at all. It doesn't look like there is only one, nothing shows up at all. @HansPassant

Comment: Consider setting the BackColor to Yellow so you can verify that the image is good.  Call BringToFront() to ensure it isn't being overlapped by another control.  Use a smaller Location so you can be sure it isn't beyond the client area of the form.  And always post the code you actually tried, this can't compile.

Answer (score 0):

As @HansPassant says in the comments, this code doesn't compile.  The following should broadly do what you want:

```
int _position = 10;

private void spawn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var pictureTest = new PictureBox();

    pictureTest.Image = Properties.Resources.testimage;
    pictureTest.Location = new Point(_position, 250);
    pictureTest.Name = "spawn1";
    pictureTest.Size = new Size(50, 50);
    pictureTest.TabIndex = 98;
    pictureTest.TabStop = false;

    this.Controls.Add(pictureTest);

    _position += 100;
}
```

Firstly, there's no need to maintain a separate array of `PictureBox`, as they are part of your form.  Secondly, as @HansPassant said - you were overlaying the images directly on top of each other, so you couldn't tell if you had 1 or 1000.